# Is there a virtual printer to output an Open Office doc to multiple images (jpg, png etc)?

Tags: openoffice.org, virtual-printer

I'm after a virtual printer which takes **each page** of "printed" output and converts into **multiple** images (one image for each page)... eg. .jpg, or .png,  etc..

I'm specifically looking for something to work with Open-Office Writer, but I assume that such a virtual printer would work across the board for any app which can send its output to a "printer".

Is there such a thing in the Ubuntu repository?

PS.  I want one "normal" picture image per page.. ie Many images are output.
...(like the Snagit virtual printer in Windows)

Comment: is the image format important? you could print to file, and set the output type as `svg`?

Comment: The format is not critical in this instance... and I've just realized how little I know about .svg as a picture format... I'd prefer a more *general* (common) format, but this may suit....  just looked at the "print to file" options, but I can't see the "svg" option anywhere... (I'll take another look at it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does it need to be an image file rather than a PDF? If not, you could use

```
sudo apt-get install cups-pdf
```

With ImageMagick you can convert PDFs to images from the command line but maybe that's getting too longwinded. Also, though I don't have it installed on the machine I'm currently used, I read on blog comment that GIMP can open PDFs...?

Comment: Thanks.. I do specifially want individual images...  I've just added more detail to my question.

Comment: I've checked it out a bit more (now that I've learnt a bit more and **almost** know what I'm doing :), and  yes, yes, yes :)  ImageMagick works! ...and so easy! ...using one of ImageMagicks tools: **convert -density 400 /home/fred/PDF/test.pdf test%d.jpg** ...  (Also I've learnt just today of a command line app to convert any/all OpenOffice format files to any other; eg. **pdf** .. it is called **unoconv** and is available in the Ubunto repository... These two tools working together make it all very simple... Thanks

Answer (score 3):

First print your document as pdf and then you can convert it to jpg or png using GIMP.

**Printing your document as pdf:**

Open your document in open office,and then click pdf option to export your document as pdf or goto file menu and choose export as pdf.

[image]

**Converting pdf to jpg|png:**

Open your pdf in GIMP(Right click your pdf and then choose **Open with GIMP
Image Editor**)

Now again goto file menu and select the option save as,Now be sure you choose the correct format.Choose JPG or PNG to save that pdf file into image format..

Comment: karthick, I'll try  your method, and see how it compares to the one I just posted....   I **think** though, that based on other .pdf to image foemats methods I've seen.... it may result in a single jpg...  (which is not what I want).. .but I'll check now...

Comment: karthick. When I open -> import the .pdf pages as "layers", it only imports the first page... When I import the pages as "images" it produces multiple **gimp** documents each of which must be saved manually and individually.. This is **definitely** no good for a 100 page original .odt ... If I've missed something, please let me know.

Comment: I'll check into Gimp a bit further, maybe it has a batch feature...  Yes, Gimp can save pages indivicually, but I would need batch capability... The ghostscript method works (see my answer), but the image quality is not very good. Gimp's pdf conversion quality is much better (+1).

Answer (score 3):

Well, i finally found a way to get it to produce individually numbered jpegs; one per page of printed output.

--(also, see the  UPDATE, below)--

First, I added a "Generic-PostScript-Printer"..
`Panel -> Sysetm -> Administration -> Printing`
or
`$ system-config-printer`

The next step is, in OpenOffice, to choose `[*] Print to file` (in the Print dialog)
and save the PostScrip file to wherever you like, eg. **~/print-to-file.ps**

The final step is to use **`ghostscript`** to do the conversion.  It has **many** *output devices*.
You can list the devices via: `$ gs -h`

To output sequentiall numbered **jpeg** images, this is the command:

```
$ gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE \  
 -sOutputFile=/home/fred/print-to-file.ps.%d.jpeg \  
 -sDEVICE=jpeg /home/fred.print-to-file.ps`
```

For the **png** format, change the filename's sufix to .png.
and use **png16 / png256 / etc**  for -sDEVICE

---

**UPDATE:**
I've just now realized that **ghostscript** can also take a **.pdf** as input...
So I tried using the **.pdf** from OpenOffice's **Export to PDF** option, as the input to `gs` (ghostscript) ...
The .odt source file  was *text-only* and the resluting images  have marginally better [kearning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kearning), so it may be worth comparing the ".pdf" as imput, vs ".ps"  for your specific situation.. font, images etc...

In summary (for this pdf method):

- Export as PDF
- `$ gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sOutputFile=/home/fred/print-to-file.pdf.%d.jpeg -sDEVICE=jpeg /home/fred.print-to-file.pdf`

---

**UPDATE 2:**
Although this method works, the quality of output images was not up to par.
Upping the **jpg** quality to 100% still produced sub-standard results..
Even **tiff** images were producing aberrations in the text (no anti-aliasing?).

Maybe there is a way to tweak **ghostscript** further, but I started looking elsewhere, and thanks to **Roddie's** suggestion, I've changed my tack and definitely prefer the "non virtual-printer" method of  **`unoconv`** + **`ImageMagick`** (mentioned in my comment to Roddie's answer)...  The image quality from ImageMagick is great! ..

A "two line" script of these two commands would make a simple "Nautilus Action", and bypass the need to directly use OpenOffice.
But if you want to convert an unsaved document to images, then you would need you use "cups-pdf" or the menu "File->Save as PDF" option instead of "unoconv".

Answer (score 1):

Its not something ive ever needed to do on linux but `cups-pdf` looks like it might do the job for you. This is available in the software centre or via the terminal:

`sudo apt-get install cups-pdf`

you can check if everything has worked by going to System > Administration > Printing, and you should have a printer there called pdf. As its installed as a printer on the system, it should work with any application that would normally print.

By default these are saved to a folder called PDF under your home folder. It is possible to change this by altering `/etc/cups/cups-pdf.conf`. Search for the OUT variable and change this to whatever you want.

Im not sure there is anyway to alter the save location on a per-usage basis, perhaps someone with more knowledge would be able to elaborate.

As a side note, Open Office writer already has an option to export to pdf in the file menu.

Comment: Thanks but I don't want a pdf in this particular case... I want one "normal" picture image per page.. ie Many images are output.  (I'll add this to my question)  ... but its good to know about the cups-pdf

Comment: Its not pretty, but `imagemagick` can convert pdfs to images, and theres a post processing section in the `cups-pdf.conf` that takes any script to run after the file has been created. If your short of other options it might be worth a shot.

Comment: Again thanks, but that won't work for me, because I want to use the standard "Print" option via the command-line.... but its good gneeral knowledge (for some situation down the track).

Comment: I just realizes that only the "export" option bypasses the print process... and that cups-pdf does use it.   (but I'm still looking for the multi image solution)

Comment: judging from the cups-pdf.conf it seems possible that you can run whatever program or script you like instead of ghostscript, as well as a post-processing script or program, so it should be possible to force it to do what you want with the help of something like imagemagick...  ;)

Answer (score 1):

We have taken the sources of cups-pdf and modified them to create svg.

This way we have a virtual network printer that creates svg for all our MS windows users.

As explained above the advantage for Linux users is smaller as they can always output ps or pdf and use inkscape or so to create svg.

However, even for Linux users it can be convenient to 'just print' and pick up the resulting svg in the user directory of the server.

Limitation we have now is that only 1 page (1 svg file) can be output at a time.

I am looking for somebody interested to package the code and place it on an ubuntu ppa.

You can mail me at ftoth AT telfort.nl

Ferry

Answer (score 0):

You should also be able to export the file to a PDF one, right from the File menu of open Office.

Comment: I specifically want multiple jpg, or png etc image as output... (like the Snagit virtual printer in Windows) ...  but thanks anyhow... Today I've certaily learnt about the pdf output possibilities of OOo :)