# How to print from an application directly to an image file

Tags: virtual-printer

I need to be able to print from a desktop app directly to an image file (PNG or JPG). There are several virtual printer drivers that do this for Windows. (ImagePrinterPro as an example) I haven't been able to find one for Ubuntu. Is there a way to use GhostScript or ImageMagick or CUPs to accomplish this? I'd like to avoid printing to PDF and then converting the PDF at the command line if possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a virtual printer to output an Open Office doc to multiple images (jpg, png etc)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14066/is-there-a-virtual-printer-to-output-an-open-office-doc-to-multiple-images-jpg)

Comment: Not unless I misunderstood it. I was hoping to print directly to an image file in a single step rather than to a PDF that requires conversion to an image file in a second step.